# WiX - Set MSI's Program name

Tags: wix, windows-installer, manifest, properties-file

in my WiX installer, if I right-click my MSI, hit *Properties*, go to *Details*, and browse the details of my MSI package, I see that under *Origin*, the default *Program name* is set to

> Windows Installer XML Toolset (3.9.....

How can I change the *Program name* that appears in the *Origin* section of my MSI's details from my WiX project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That property is in the Summary Information Stream: [Creating Application Summary property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368056(v=vs.85).aspx)  Windows Explorer simply calls it Program.

WiX follows the MSI standard and put's the name of the tool and version that created the MSI.  WiX doesn't have any attributes in the schema to override this.  If it really bugs you, you'd need to do a postbuild script to tweak the summary information stream prior to any code signing that you may do.

Comment: Ah, so it is a standard thing :) In that case, may as well preserve it as it gives tool version number and everything.